# Doxygen group warning: end of file inside a group

Tags: c, module, grouping, doxygen

I am attempting to use a doxygen(v1.8.9.1) `@defgroup` comment in a C header file that finishes with an `@{` as follows:

```
/** @file foo.h
 * @brief This is a foo file
 */

#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

#include somebar.h

/** @defgroup foo Foo
 * @details This foo file does foo stuff
 * @{
 */

#ifdef __cpluplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

/* foo declarations here with standard doxygen documentation */

#ifdef __cpluplus
    }
#endif

/** @} */

#endif
```

This matches the example usage at [doxygen-Grouping-Modules](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#modules) however, when I build this, this gives an error at the end of the file `warning: end of file while inside a group`.

However everything runs fine if the opening `@{` is in a separate doxygen comment a la:

```
/** @defgroup foo Foo
 * @details This foo file does foo stuff
 */
/** @{ */
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the message on windows with either 1.8.9, 1.8.9.1 or with the current head version from github. Any special settings in the Doxyfile (I used the one generated with doxygen -g).

Comment: Hmm. Thats odd. Im not using a vanilla doxyfile, but its so far just changing basic things like paths, project name brief etc, inlining simple structs, custom latex header that adjusts page numbers, no extraction of local classes, hidden undoc members and classes, not showing include files, not sorting member docs, not generating TODO list, not showing used files and not showing files (files are added in specific order in INPUT)

Comment: I checked also that all groups are otherwise opened and closed properly and they are :\

Comment: What happens if you use a vanilla Doxyfile on the posted example? What happens if you use your own Doxyfile on the posted example?

Comment: Hm. for both doxyfiles with a project with just the posted code (+ one documented bar() function) there is no problems. So I am doing something wrong in my documentation. I don't know what because at this stage if I've checked it once I've checked it a hundred times :\

Comment: Oh gee! When changing between the two styles of opening groups I had left the separated group opener comment following the combined one and just removed the extra star (i.e. changed `/** @{ */` to `/* @{ */`) thinking this removed it from Doxygen's parsing... but apparently not! So Doxygen ended up thinking I was opening two groups and only closing one!
So essentially doxygen noticed a `@{` in a regular, non-documentation, comment block. I'd imagine this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I had been trying the two different styles of opening a group I had left the old group opener in a non-documentation comment that doxygen is apparently still treating like a documentation comment. This meant that doxygen thought I was opening *two* groups and only closing one of them!

E.G.

```
/** @defgroup foo Foo
 * @details This foo file does foo stuff
 * @{
 */

/* @{ */ // Note, only a single leading star so should not be treated as doxygen comment, yet it is.

/* Some code and documentation that is in a group here. */

/**@} */ // Close one group here but the second, unasked-for, group is not closed yet.
/* EOF */
```